# Intersection with redbeanphp

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have an array $mycontacts of beans of type $contact

where:

```
$contact->id = $x
$contact->name = $y
$contact->email= $z
```

I want to check the $mycontacts array against a second array $contacted also of type $contact.

I want to perform $mycontacts - $contacted to yield a subset which I have not contacted based on the email parameter. Now i could do something like

```
foreach ($mycontacts as $mycontact) {
     loop through $contacted and compare $contacted->email to $mycontact->email
}
```

Is there a better way to do this either with php, redbean or mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM   contact
        WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT mycontact.id
                          FROM   contact AS mycontact 
                          WHERE  1/* your condition*/)';
$rows = R::getAll( $sql );
$contactsMinusMyContacts = R::convertToBeans( 'contact', $rows );
```

This code should be the best performing, as it runs nearly entirely on the database, which is the best place to work with sets of data. It first selects all contacts, then subtracts "my contacts" and returns the result. RedBean then converts it back to beans.